# Android Jetpack Compose by rememberSaveable State does not survive Back Button

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I cannot find the `savedInstanceState` function shown in code examples in the [Restore UI state after activity or process recreation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state) section of the [State and Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) that the section says *"retains state across activity and process recreation."*

I did find the `androidx.compose.runtime.saveable` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary) which contains `rememberSaveable` which seems to be the renaming or replacement of `savedInstanceState` and its documentation also says *"... the stored value will survive the activity or process recreation."*

However, when I use it in my code, the state does not survive the back button, although it does survive rotations. That's contrary to what the documentation says.

```
package com.example.jetwatch

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(bundle)
  setContent {
   MaterialTheme(colors = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) darkColors() else lightColors()) {
    Surface {
     Column {
      Row {
       Column {
        var m by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
        Text("m = $m")
        Button(onClick = { ++m }) {
         Text("bump")
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> the state does not survive the back button

In that sample, this is expected behavior. The default behavior of back navigation is to destroy the activity. Saved instance state is discarded at this point. This is not unique to Compose and has been stock Android behavior since Android 1.0.

> That's contrary to what the documentation says.

"Process termination", as used in the documentation, refers to this flow:

- User is in your app
- User switches to the launcher (via home navigation) or to another app (e.g., via the overview screen)
- Over the course of the next several minutes (but fewer than 30), Android terminates your process while it is in the background
- Use returns to your app by one means or another

At that point, Android will fork a fresh process for you and try to restore your UI to where you had been before the user switched away from your app. The saved instance state is part of that restoration.

Comment: thanks; to clarify for other readers: the back button causes `finish()` to be called, which makes this behavior reasonable, but on the other hand, killing the process by swiping it away does not cause `finish()` (or `onDestry()`) to be called and yet loses the saved state, probably because it is a `kill -9` under the hood as opposed to a `kill -15`. not an ideal world but we have to live in it.

Comment: @user2297550: The point behind saved instance state is to be able to restore the UI for cases where the *user* might think the app was still running but where the *system* had other ideas due to low memory conditions. Swiping the task off the overview screen means the user is very specifically saying that they do not want the task anymore, so there is no need to hold onto the saved instance state.

Comment: Swiping away the app is `task clear`, which is effectively "kill all activities in this task". This is expected. (I'm just reiterating what is being said, really)

Comment: This is interesting, because I had interpreted it as the process being terminated for any reason, not just for inactivity. So I guess this means on Desktop, `rememberSaveable` really does nothing, because desktop OSen never terminate the process for that reason. They might terminate it for using too much memory, but by the definition in this answer, that isn't included, so it does nothing. So really what I am now looking for is something like `rememberSaveable` but which actually saves in all situations. Because the OS might reboot and I still want my app to be in the state it was left.

Comment: @Hakanai I am also wondering, why the API does not offer a "remberPersistently".

Comment: @ceving it really sounds like this _is_ achieved using persistence - but the situations in which the system will trigger restoring(?) the value are just not what we want? It can't possibly be decided at save-time, because you never know whether you're about to crash. But also yes, what I'd like is framework for more persistent state in general. When I restart my computer, macOS' TextEdit.app comes back up with the previous stuff in the file that I hadn't yet saved. That sort of quality persistent behaviour that helps users trust your app. That's what I want.